# Suppressing duplicate values in groups

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report with 2 bands:

1. A detail band used to display rows that have Group=N i.e. if Group <> N, it is hidden
2. A group footer, used to display an aggregate of rows that have Group=Y i.e. if Group <> Y, it is hidden

Both bands display a Date, Name, and Amount. The group footer aggregates the Amount field.
I would like to suppress repeating Dates.

E.g, given the following data:

```
+------------+------+-------+--------+
|    Date    | Name | Group | Amount |
+------------+------+-------+--------+
| 2020-06-01 | A    | Y     |      5 |
| 2020-06-01 | A    | Y     |     10 |
| 2020-06-01 | D    | N     |      2 |
| 2020-06-01 | Z    | Y     |      4 |
| 2020-06-02 | B    | N     |      1 |
| 2020-06-02 | G    | Y     |      6 |
| 2020-06-02 | G    | Y     |      3 |
+------------+------+-------+--------+
```

It should display:

```
+------------+------+--------+
|  Date      | Name | Amount |
+------------+------+--------+
| 2020-06-01 | A    |     15 |
|            | D    |      2 |
|            | Z    |      4 |
| 2020-06-02 | B    |      1 |
|            | G    |      9 |
+------------+------+--------+
```

With isPrintRepeatedValues="false", it duplicates dates as they are in different bands:

```
+------------+------+--------+
|  Date      | Name | Amount |
+------------+------+--------+
| 2020-06-01 | A    |     15 |
| 2020-06-01 | D    |      2 |
|            | Z    |      4 |
| 2020-06-02 | B    |      1 |
| 2020-06-02 | G    |      9 |
+------------+------+--------+
```

Adding a:

```
<group name="DateGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></groupExpression>
 </group>
```

and suppressing the Date fields with the expressions:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{DateGroup_COUNT} == 1]]</printWhenExpression>
```

doesn't work either, as the following display shows. I've included the Group and DateGroup_Count values for debugging:

```
+------------+------+--------+-------+-----------------+
|    Date    | Name | Amount | Group | DateGroup_COUNT |
+------------+------+--------+-------+-----------------+
|            | A    |     15 | Y     |               2 |
|            | D    |      2 | N     |               3 |
|            | Z    |      4 | Y     |               4 |
| 2020-06-02 | B    |      1 | N     |               1 |
|            | G    |      9 | Y     |               3 |
+------------+------+--------+-------+-----------------+
```

2020-06-01 should be displayed in the first row, but in the above the DateGroup_COUNT value represents the last row in the aggregated band, so the Date field is suppressed when it shouldn't be.

Note that the above can possibly be achieved in a single band. It represents a simplified version of a report that cannot be achieved using a single band as it:

- calculates the Amount column differently in each band
- has different fields in each band which would need to be selectively shown/hidden. These would also overlap

The CSV used for the data source:

```
Date,Name,Group,Amount
2020-06-01,A,Y,5
2020-06-01,A,Y,10
2020-06-01,D,N,2
2020-06-01,Z,Y,4
2020-06-02,B,N,1
2020-06-02,G,Y,6
2020-06-02,G,Y,3
```

The JRXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="duplicatetest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="datasuppressiontestdata"/>
    <field name="Date" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Group" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <variable name="groupTotal" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Aggregate" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Amount}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="DateGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="Aggregate">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Group}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="30">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[EQUALS($F{Group}, "Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="DateGroup" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" printWhenGroupChanges="DateGroup">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{DateGroup_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <paragraph lineSpacing="Fixed"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="134" y="0" width="116" height="30"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="260" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{groupTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="458" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{DateGroup_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="389" y="0" width="68" height="30"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Group}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="134" y="0" width="116" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="260" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="458" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[DateGroup_COUNT]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="0" width="68" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Group]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!EQUALS($F{Group}, "Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
            <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="DateGroup" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" printWhenGroupChanges="DateGroup">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{DateGroup_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="134" y="0" width="116" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="260" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="458" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{DateGroup_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="389" y="0" width="68" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Group}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I don't think the suggested linked answers are directly applicable. The first answer is quite a nice solution to a different problem, and prompted me to add a DateGroup, but this still doesn't correctly handle display of the Date field in the aggregate band. At this stage, I can't see that the second linked answer is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created new variable to read DateGroup count . On change of each date reset to 1.
And printed Date only when Dategroup is 1.

Check below jrxml. It gives your desired output.

[image: Ouput]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="duplicatetest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="04479c0d-d012-45d8-a8d1-f281276aba62">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="datasuppressiontestdata"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="Date" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Group" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <variable name="groupTotal" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Aggregate" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Amount}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="COUNT_GROUP_1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="DateGroup" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="DateGroup">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[( $V{Aggregate_COUNT} == 1) ? $V{COUNT_GROUP_1} + 1 : $V{COUNT_GROUP_1}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="DateGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="Aggregate">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Group}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="30">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[EQUALS($F{Group}, "Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
                <textField pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" printWhenGroupChanges="DateGroup" uuid="16819840-1496-42ac-aec8-02e50a104608">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{COUNT_GROUP_1}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <paragraph lineSpacing="Fixed"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="134" y="0" width="116" height="30" uuid="5008a25a-6654-4ffc-95dd-cdefac6b1c3a"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="260" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="c89330be-7a7b-4721-b881-10e5df8ced68"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{groupTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="458" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="5dd2909c-4ffb-4296-9a42-3656bed378fe"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{DateGroup_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="389" y="0" width="68" height="30" uuid="61b8eb92-90ec-4727-a69c-642f063f08fe"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Group}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="f05195da-f90c-4026-9e38-89a902853871"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="134" y="0" width="116" height="30" uuid="2d40f4cc-a795-4e67-9fac-7a6e77085de3"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="260" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="e5c44c50-93da-45a0-8a21-18fab3295972"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="458" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="1b22596b-22e0-4b22-b2ab-9ed699ddd61f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[DateGroup_COUNT]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="0" width="68" height="30" uuid="8210e103-4473-4a5e-a915-a568356f76ac"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Group]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!EQUALS($F{Group}, "Y")]]></printWhenExpression>
            <textField pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" printWhenGroupChanges="DateGroup" uuid="9112a549-c2e1-4b49-996e-d12f5f1307cf">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{COUNT_GROUP_1}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="134" y="0" width="116" height="30" uuid="111ee635-3426-4a2b-8f68-3e4e6dc003c3"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="260" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="c0eac89a-54ac-4480-9fa1-3c841aed7d89"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="458" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="b2ff7aaf-ab81-4b3d-a45f-9094044af7bf"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{DateGroup_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="389" y="0" width="68" height="30" uuid="5ac47f28-41e3-4940-bcdb-91b2ba85f30b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Group}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the task right, all you need is to create two groups and show total for 2nd group.

You can solve this task in 5 steps:

1. Sort data by `Date` and `Name` fields.
2. Create group by `Date` field
3. Create group by `Name` field
4. Create variable to show sum of all `Amount` values at each group by `Name`
5. Create simple report using *Detail* and *Column Header* bands only.

#### The report's template

The template is using *data adapter* based on your *csv* file.

The *jrxml* code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="duplicatetest" pageWidth="390" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="350" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="datasuppressiontestdata"/>
    <field name="Date" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Group" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <sortField name="Date"/>
    <sortField name="Name"/>
    <variable name="groupTotal" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="nameGroup" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Amount}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="dateGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="nameGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="130" y="0" width="120" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="250" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="yyyy-MM-dd">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{dateGroup_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="130" y="0" width="120" height="30">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{nameGroup_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
                <reportElement x="250" y="0" width="100" height="30">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{nameGroup_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{groupTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I used *printWhenExpression* property for showing data of only first record for each `Date` and `Name` groups. I removed all "duplicates" with help of this trick.

With help of `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` property I hid all blank lines (for cases `$V{nameGroup_COUNT} > 1`).

The last trick is to set `evaluationTime="Auto"` property for *textField* with total sum.

#### Output result

The generated report looks like this at *JSS*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. The sample I provided uses two bands to demonstrate the problem of selectively turning on/off bands. The actual report has three bands which are turned on/off based on different criteria, the columns values are derived differently in each, and there are different fields in each. Trying to do it all in one band would require selectively turning on/off fields, and they would need to overlap. Not easy to maintain